# pgloader 's errors Max connetions reached

Tags: postgresql, pgloader

This is my first try using pgloader in order to import an sql database into a PostgreSQL database, and I have this error when execution the pgloader commande :

> MAX connections reached, increase value of TDS_MAX_CONN

I tried already to increase the value of `max_connections` and `shared_buffers` in the `postgresql.conf`, but nothing has been changed.

```
max_connections = 300 
shared_buffers=256MB
```

Any solutions plz ?

Comment: SQL Server <> PostgreSQL - please correct your tags.

Comment: Did you have a look at https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/issues/605

Comment: `TDS_MAX_CONN` would be on the SQL Server/FreeTDS end, so changing the Postgres settings is not going to help. Follow the link @greg posted.

Comment: Thank you for your interactions , I understand that i have to increase the TDS_MAX_CONN on the sql Server ,but the sql server is a windows server 2003 , so i don't understand where i'm supposed to find the tds file configuration ?